# CMake install is not installing libraries on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake

For some reason, the below CMake file fails to install the project libraries. It creates the directory in the right location, and it even recursively installs the headers... But it fails to install the library. How can this be fixed?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyLib)

include_directories(include)
add_library(MyLib SHARED source/stuff.cpp)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM MATCHES "Windows")
target_link_libraries(MyLib DbgHelp ws2_32 iphlpapi)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "../../devel_artifacts")
endif(CMAKE_SYSTEM MATCHES "Windows")

install(TARGETS MyLib LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib"
                      ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib"
                      COMPONENT library)
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION include)
```

Answer (score 16):

You're just missing the `RUNTIME DESTINATION` argument in the [`install(TARGETS...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/install.html) command.

CMake treats shared libraries as runtime objects on "DLL platforms" like Windows.  If you change your command to:

```
install(TARGETS MyLib LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib"
                      ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib"
                      RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin"
                      COMPONENT library)
```

then you should find that MyLib.dll ends up in "devel_artifacts/bin".