# Using constant folder with cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a constant `MYPROJECT` in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export MYPROJECT = /home/loom/my_project
```

I can see the constant is defined in the terminal:

```
loom@loom$ ls -ld $MYPROJECT
drwxr-xr-x 25 loom loom 4096 Jul 21 22:12 /home/loom/my_project
```

I tried to use the constant in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(booo src/main.cpp ${MYPROJECT}/foo/trunk/bar/File.h)
```

However, it produces an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    /foo/trunk/bar/File.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: booo
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "booo".
```

It is processed without errors if I have used explicit path without `$MYPROJECT`:

```
add_executable(booo src/main.cpp /home/loom/my_project/foo/trunk/bar/File.h)
```

How to use path defined in `.bashrc` in cmake?

Comment: Just two thoughts: Out of bad experiences of using environment variables directly inside CMake projects, I would recommend to pass the constant to CMake via its `-D` option, e.g. `cmake -DMYPROJECT:PATH=$MYPROJECT ..`. Then CMake would cache this value in its own internal variable (it will get part of your project's configuration, important if CMake configuration step is retriggered). And listing a header file in in `add_library()`/`add_executable()` will only list/show them in IDE projects. You also need something like `include_directories(${MYPROJECT}/foo/trunk/bar)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
add_executable(booo src/main.cpp ${MYPROJECT}/foo/trunk/bar/File.h)
```

use

```
add_executable(booo src/main.cpp $ENV{MYPROJECT}/foo/trunk/bar/File.h)
```

The CMake documentation states:

> Use the syntax $ENV{VAR} to read environment variable VAR. See also
>   the set() command to set ENV{VAR}.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/ENV.html

Answer (score 2):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

There are a lot of ways you could do this in CMake. Out of bad experiences with using environment variables directly inside CMake projects (they have to be valid not only during the first call to CMake configuration/generation but also later during all consecutive builds), I would recommend to transfer your constant into a cached CMake variable.

I'm using one of the following ways in my projects:

1. Injecting `MYPROJECT` CMake via its [`-D option`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake.1.html), e.g.

   ```
   cmake -DMYPROJECT:PATH=$MYPROJECT ..
   ```

   Then CMake would cache this value in its own `MYPROJECT` internal variable.
2. When you get values from the "outside" you should think about what to do if no value is provided or it's not a valid directory. Throwing a fatal error and/or retry with a default value?

   The following example shows only transformation steps and sanity checks (no default value retry):

   ```
   if (NOT DEFINED MYPROJECT OR NOT IS_DIRECTORY MYPROJECT)
       file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "$ENV{MYPROJECT}" _ENV_MYPROJECT_REL)
       get_filename_component(_ENV_MYPROJECT "${_ENV_MYPROJECT_REL}" ABSOLUTE)
       if (NOT _ENV_MYPROJECT)
           message(FATAL_ERROR "Environment variable MYPROJECT not provided.")
       else()
           set(MYPROJECT "${_ENV_MYPROJECT}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
       endif()
   endif()
   ```
3. Using [`find_path()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_path.html), which will also cache its result:

   ```
   find_path(
       MYPROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR 
           NAMES File.h
           PATHS ENV MYPROJECT
                 /home/loom/my_project
           PATH_SUFFIXES foo/trunk/bar
   )
   if (NOT MYPROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR)
       ...
   ```
4. Or - assuming your external project does not only consists of header files but also libraries like `foo.a` - following CMake's [A Sample Find Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#a-sample-find-module) and extending the `find_path()` code from above by:

   ```
   find_library(
        MYPROJECT_LIBRARY
           NAMES foo
           PATHS ENV MYPROJECT
           PATH_SUFFIXES foo/lib
   )        

   if(MYPROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR AND MYPROJECT_LIBRARY AND NOT TARGET MyProject::MyProject)
       add_library(MyProject::MyProject UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
       set_target_properties(
           MyProject::MyProject 
           PROPERTIES
               IMPORTED_LOCATION "${MYPROJECT_LIBRARY}"
               INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${MYPROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}"
       )
   endif()
   ```

   Now you can use it directly as any other CMake target with

   ```
   add_executable(booo src/main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(booo MyProject::MyProject)
   ```

**More References**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [preferred cmake project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534115/preferred-cmake-project-structure)