# Why cmake ignores the Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE environment variable?

Tags: boost, cmake

The following command works for me well:

```
cmake ../ -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=BOOL:ON
```

i.e., cmake ignores system `BoostConfig.cmake`, which is what I need. But if I try to do the same via an environment variable:

```
Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=ON cmake ../
```

cmake still reads `BoostConfig.cmake` and I got the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib64/boost/BoostConfig.cmake:64 (get_target_property):
```

I've tried also setting to `TRUE`, `BOOL:ON`, etc. as well. Using cmake version 3.3.1. Any hint?

**UPDATE**

Adding

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE TRUE)
```

into `CMakeList.txt` works well, but the same line added into `PreLoad.cmake` does not. In the second case, running cmake with trace and debug options gives the following first few log lines:

```
Configuring Debug su3-dense ...
Running with debug output on.
Running with trace output on.
/home/langr/projects/su3dense/PreLoad.cmake(1):  set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE TRUE )
/home/langr/projects/su3dense/CMakeLists.txt(1):  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 )
...
```

So, the `PreLoad.cmake` file is apparently processed and the variable `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` is set. Why is this setting then ignored?

**UPDATE 2**

I finally got it working by writing

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE TRUE CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

into `PreLoad.cmake`.

Comment: If I look at the [`FindBoost.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L231) source code this check is not meant for environment variables, but for `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` CMake variable only. Can you please give a reference for why this should work with an environment variable? Your first `-D` call seems to be the valid solution.

Comment: @Florian: In fact I cannot, I'm new to cmake and thought it considers environment variables for all internal variables automatically. My first `-D` call is a valid solution, but unfortunately it requires me to change some build script being a part of a Git project. Setting an environment variable in my `.bashrc` would be a much more elegant solution here.

Comment: Could one of the solutions I've posted in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758798/using-constant-folder-with-cmake/33790663#33790663) be feasible? You could e.g. extend your main `CMakeLists.txt` to transfer the content of the environment variable into a CMake cached variable. Or if you don't want to change your `CMakeLists.txt` you could put the code into `PreLoad.cmake` (for details see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)).

Comment: @Florian: I've tried the `PreLoad.cmake` solution but it does not work for me. Please, see the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a `PreLoad.cmake` file with the following contents finally works for me:

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE TRUE CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

Thanks Florian for help.

Comment: You're welcome. And I appologize that I forgot to mention the scope of `PreLoad.cmake`. Since it's not included in your main `CMakeLists.txt` but rather loaded before your main `CMakeLists.txt`, all variables set in `PreLoad.cmake` have to be cached variables - if they should also be visible in your main `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem but with a different cause and solution.

In my case CMake ignored `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` because I used the [full signature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#id3) of `find_package` in which config mode is used.

This did NOT work:

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
find_package(BOOST_LIB 1.66 NAMES Boost REQUIRED)  # full signature
```

This did work:

```
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
find_package(Boost 1.66 REQUIRED)  # basic signature
```