# How to organize project using cmake and separated headers

Tags: c++, header, cmake, organization

I am currently starting a new project using C++ and CMake,
in my last project I organized the code the following:

```
src
|--foo
|  |--bar.cpp
|  |--bar.hpp
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|--baz
|  |--anotherFoo
|  |  |--Bahama.cpp
|  |  |--Bahama.hpp
|  |  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--baz.cpp
|  |--baz.hpp
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|--CMakeLists.txt
```

so every subdirectory got its own `CMakeLists.txt`, which was included as library from other `CMakeList` files.
Now I want to separate the `.hpp` and the `.cpp` files.
Something like this:

```
src
|--foo
|  |--bar.cpp
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|--baz
|  |--anotherFoo
|  |  |--Bahama.cpp
|  |  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--baz.cpp
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|--CMakeLists.txt

include
|--foo
|  |--bar.hpp
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|--baz
|  |--anotherFoo
|  |  |--Bahama.hpp
|  |  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |--baz.hpp
|  |--CMakeLists.txt
|--CMakeLists.txt
```

What I am supposed to do with the `CmakeLists` files?
Do I also need a `CMakeLists` file in every subdirectory, like I did in my example above? Or is there another way to do this?
What do I write in this CMake files
In the future I also want to add documentation with doxygen, how can I enable Doxygen support via Cmake in a structure like this?

should also every subdirectory get its own?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534115/preferred-cmake-project-structure) and [that](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/289348/directory-organization-of-a-cmake-c-repository-containing-several-projects) questions, as well as [this repo](https://github.com/Barthelemy/CppProjectTemplate).

Comment: as for me, I will recommend separate includes to `project/include` folder (as in github repo above), as opposed to `project/src`. Also, I will add that I prefer to place includes in `include` folder only if they are not likely to change (e.g. library api, etc.). For "work-in-progress" includes: just place them in your `src` folder with your implementation (.cpp) files.

Comment: @rsht thanks for the all the information, the repo is realy nice

Comment: @rsht the repo would be exactly my set up, except I am not familiar with  CPack (but I will research about it) and I dont want to have two projects in one repo, so how would I setup the project, with all the cmake files,  when I only want to use Boost.Test, Doxygen and Cmake for a single project?
Sorry I am a Cmake beginner :\

Comment: you can just treat each project from the repo as separate (e.g. go and copy all template files from [this path](https://github.com/Barthelemy/CppProjectTemplate/tree/master/ProjA)). For all things that you don't know or that doesn't work - google it. If you find yourself really stuck on something - write here. But don't expect guys here to setup your cmake project for you :) good luck!

Comment: Why do you need to split headers? It'll brings some inconvenience to development process (already is...), so why to do that? Personally, I see no reason to do that...